# FullCalendar v6 eventContent interferes with dayMaxEvents

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am in the middle of upgrading from FullCalendar v3 to v6. I noticed that it now has an overflow feature, specified with the `dayMaxEvents` + `dayMaxEventRows` options.

However, I also need to override `eventContent()` to inject additional elements into the event text, and for reasons unknown, whenever I have the `eventContent()` callback specified, the overflow link will never appear and the events will overflow out of the cell.

Is there something specific I need to do within `eventContent()` to be compatible with `dayMaxEvents`, or is this a bug I should file with FullCalendar?

Also - as a side question - what's the difference between the `dayMaxEvents` and `dayMaxEventRows` options? I can't tell from reading the docs.

Here's what the calendar looks like with the `eventContent()` callback commented out:

[image: Calendar with no custom content and overflow link visible]

And here it is with our custom content enabled (the yellow dot on one event):

[image: Calendar with custom content - events overflow out of the cell]

Comment: `Is there something specific I need to do within eventContent()`...it might depend what you've done already. Please provide us with a [mre] of your issue so we can see what's going on (as a reminder, see also [ask])

Comment: `Also - as a side question`...please don't ask secondary questions within a single post. Write a new question if you have a specific issue about that. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I made a CodePen to reproduce the problem and it didn't occur. Then I started digging into my code (expecially custom CSS) to find the cause, and the problem somehow stopped occurring. I'm not sure what to say at this point.

I guess if nothing else comes up in the next couple days, I'll close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving this here in case it helps somebody someday:

I also stumbled across a similar problem: my events were never hidden under "More" link when using a custom component for an event.

What helped: I set `min-height` equal to the height of my custom Event component on the `.fc-daygrid-event`. My guess is that it helps the library to calculate the height of the events list correctly and decide whether it should hide some events or not :)

Comment: Thanks! The problem seems to be sporadic for me, but after adding that style I haven't reproduced it again yet. I'll optimistically take that to mean this solution works.